# How connect MySQL to Node.js CRUD

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, windows

I've been using mongoDB forever.  How do I switch over to MySQL?  Currently, I have no idea where to look.  Should I use MySQL workbench?  PGAdmin4?  How the heck do I go about doing this or learning to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [JavaScript mysql package](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql). It's the most popular package for working with MySQL in JavaScript, and the GitHub readme should walk you through most steps on using it.

If you'd like a second option, I've also had experience with the [node-mysql](https://github.com/redblaze/node-mysql) package (which depends on the mysql package). It's a bit simpler to use and it worked great for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I added in this post, How to work with MySQL in Nodejs.

Step 1: Create table in you MySQL DB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'primary key',
  `employee_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'employee name',
  `employee_salary` double NOT NULL COMMENT 'employee salary',
  `employee_age` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'employee age'
);
```

Step 2: Install all package using this command :

```
npm install --save mysql express body-parser
```

Step 3: Create app.js File in same directory

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//start mysql connection
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost', //mysql database host name
  user     : 'root', //mysql database user name
  password : '', //mysql database password
  database : 'dummy_db' //mysql database name
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('You are now connected...')
})
//end mysql connection

//start body-parser configuration
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
//end body-parser configuration

//create app server
var server = app.listen(3000,  "127.0.0.1", function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

});

//rest api to get all results
app.get('/employees', function (req, res) {
   connection.query('select * from employee', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});

//rest api to get a single employee data
app.get('/employees/:id', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req);
   connection.query('select * from employee where id=?', [req.params.id], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});

//rest api to create a new record into mysql database
app.post('/employees', function (req, res) {
   var postData  = req.body;
   connection.query('INSERT INTO employee SET ?', postData, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});

//rest api to update record into mysql database
app.put('/employees', function (req, res) {
   connection.query('UPDATE `employee` SET `employee_name`=?,`employee_salary`=?,`employee_age`=? where `id`=?', [req.body.employee_name,req.body.employee_salary, req.body.employee_age, req.body.id], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});

//rest api to delete record from mysql database
app.delete('/employees', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.body);
   connection.query('DELETE FROM `employee` WHERE `id`=?', [req.body.id], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end('Record has been deleted!');
    });
});
```

Step 4: Start the server using this command:

```
 node app.js
```

Follow this [link](https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/node-js-rest-api-add-edit-delete-record-mysql-using-express/)  if you face any issue.